# How can I track total data usage for individual apps on iOS7?

Tags: ios

I have a data limited 4g contract and my iPad is downloading huge chunks of data overnight, daily. I need to be able to track how much data individual apps are using, however as I am connecting to 4g through wifi, I can't just check mobile (celluar) data usage.

How can I track the total data each app is using, both over mobile networks and wifi?

Comment: What do you mean "I am connecting to 4g through wifi" - those are two different technologies. Or does your wifi usage also count against your 4G contract data usage?

Comment: @mjturner He means that he has a 4G hotspot.

Comment: Please ask for this feature at Apple so they'll consider adding it. The more people that ask the more likely it will get added http://www.apple.com/feedback/

Answer (score 1):

Data Usage - Onavo Count - Data manager =
tracks each app =
would be perfect and its free

Comment: I took a look at that, but it filters all data through a VPN. Not really happy with the thought they have access to all of my data.

Comment: @danixd If you're using encrypted protocols like HTTPS, then there's nothing to worry about. Besides, it's not like HTTP even at your own home is safe.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS system does not save the data usage for single apps.

But you could jailbreak your iPhone to get a feature like this, there are tweaks for that.

Comment: What type of tweaks?

Comment: I dont know the exact name but Cydia has apps which are tracking the data usage of every single app.